# Group by Column in Dataframe and create seperate csv for all the group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a huge CSV file of 100kb  which contains records. Example like below

```
city         employee

california   jhon
delhi        kumar
us           raj
california   brakers
us           kroja
...
```

So I want to group them and stored in a separate CSV file

My output result for above example would be

```
city         employee

california   jhon
california   brakers
delhi        kumar
us           raj
us           kroja
```

Will I have to like sort/group by the city in the data frame and then have a for loop and iterate through the entire data frame?

And her is my code

```
New_data=pd.read_csv("citynames.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1") 
Aftergrouping_data=New_data.groupby("city")
#print(Aftergrouping_data.groups)

for name,group in Aftergrouping_data:
    print(name)
    group.to_csv("aftergrouping.csv".format(name), index=False)
```

The problem is its overriding the values in for loop and displays the last group data. but I want all the grouped data in the file.

Thank you In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, two aspects seem clear:

1. You want to **sort** data rather than **group** data. You can sort data without a `groupby` object.
2. You want to export the dataframe to a **single csv file**. There's no need to use iteration for this task.

You can simply use `sort_values` followed by `to_csv`:

```
# read file
df = pd.read_csv('citynames.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

# sort by 'city', ascending
df = df.sort_values('city')

# export to csv
df.to_csv('citynames_out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Tq so much sir for help. One more question `Aftergrouping_data=New_data.groupby("city")` then i performs `numpy` as `Aftergrouping_data.agg(np.size)` know the question is how to store the result in a csv file

Comment: @lavakumar, Sorry, I don't know *why* you need `groupby` for the task described in *this* question, nor why you need to aggregate by size. I suggest you ask a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for different requirements, showing clearly your desired output.